# Newbe Trouble Running Grails 2.4.4

Tags: grails, stack-overflow

I'm a Grails newbe and cannot get Grails to run. I'm using Grails 2.4.4 and JDK version 7 (on Windows 7).  When I run `grails` or `grails -version` on the command line, I get a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. I've tried many combinations of JDK versions and Grails versions and always have the same error right off the bat. I've also changed the JVM thread stack size using _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xss1m (and many other sizes). Still no luck.
Here's what I get when I turn the DEBUG environment variable on:

```
C:\Users\jpeil>if "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" setlocal

C:\Users\jpeil>set DIRNAME=C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4\bin\ 

C:\Users\jpeil>if "C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4\bin\" == "" set DIRNAME=.\ 

C:\Users\jpeil>CALL "C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4\bin\\startGrails.bat"  

C:\Users\jpeil>if "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" setlocal

C:\Users\jpeil>set CLASS=org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter 

C:\Users\jpeil>if exist "C:\Users\jpeil/.groovy/preinit.bat" call "C:\Users\jpeil/.groovy/preinit.bat" 

C:\Users\jpeil>set COMMAND_COM="cmd.exe" 

C:\Users\jpeil>if exist "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" set COMMAND_COM="C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" 

C:\Users\jpeil>if exist "C:\windows\command.com" set COMMAND_COM="C:\windows\command.com" 

C:\Users\jpeil>set FIND_EXE="find.exe" 

C:\Users\jpeil>if exist "C:\windows\system32\find.exe" set FIND_EXE="C:\windows\system32\find.exe" 

C:\Users\jpeil>if exist "C:\windows\command\find.exe" set FIND_EXE="C:\windows\command\find.exe" 

C:\Users\jpeil>if not "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25" == "" goto have_JAVA_HOME 

C:\Users\jpeil>if "5" == "\" SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_2 

C:\Users\jpeil>"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /C DIR "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25"   2>&1  | "C:\windows\system32\find.exe" /I /C "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25"  1>nul 

C:\Users\jpeil>if not errorlevel 1 goto check_GRAILS_HOME 

C:\Users\jpeil>if "C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4" == "" set GRAILS_HOME=C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4\bin\.. 

C:\Users\jpeil>if "4" == "\" SET GRAILS_HOME=C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4. 

C:\Users\jpeil>for %x in ("C:\Users\jpeil") do set SHORTHOME=%~fsx 

C:\Users\jpeil>set SHORTHOME=C:\Users\jpeil 

C:\Users\jpeil>if "x" == "x" set GRAILS_AGENT_CACHE_DIR=C:\Users\jpeil/.grails/2.4.4/ 

C:\Users\jpeil>set SPRINGLOADED_PARAMS="profile=grails;cacheDir=C:\Users\jpeil/.grails/2.4.4/" 

C:\Users\jpeil>if not exist "C:\Users\jpeil/.grails/2.4.4/" mkdir "C:\Users\jpeil/.grails/2.4.4/" 

C:\Users\jpeil>if "" == "" (
type "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\include\classfile_constants.h"   2>nul  | findstr /R /C:"#define JVM_CLASSFILE_MAJOR_VERSION 5[23]"  1>nul  
 if not errorlevel 1 set GRAILS_NO_PERMGEN=1 
) 

C:\Users\jpeil>set AGENT_STRING=-javaagent:C:/grails-2.4.4/grails-2.4.4/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar -Xverify:none -Dspringloaded.synchronize=true -Djdk.reflect.allowGetCallerClass=true -Dspringloaded=\""profile=grails;cacheDir=C:\Users\jpeil/.grails/2.4.4/"\" 

C:\Users\jpeil>set DISABLE_RELOADING= 

C:\Users\jpeil>if "" == "" (
set GRAILS_OPTS=-server -Xmx768M -Xms64M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  
 if not "1" == "1" (set GRAILS_OPTS=-server -Xmx768M -Xms64M -XX:PermSize=32m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ) 
) 

C:\Users\jpeil>if "@eval[2+2]" == "4" goto 4NT_args 

C:\Users\jpeil>set CMD_LINE_ARGS= 

C:\Users\jpeil>set CP= 

C:\Users\jpeil>set INTERACTIVE=true 

C:\Users\jpeil>if "x" == "x" goto execute 

C:\Users\jpeil>set STARTER_CLASSPATH=C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-2.3.7.jar;C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4\dist\grails-bootstrap-2.4.4.jar 

C:\Users\jpeil>if exist "C:\Users\jpeil/.groovy/init.bat" call "C:\Users\jpeil/.groovy/init.bat" 

C:\Users\jpeil>if "x" == "x" goto after_classpath 

C:\Users\jpeil>if "x" == "xtrue" (set AGENT= )  else (if "xtrue" == "xtrue" (set AGENT=-javaagent:C:/grails-2.4.4/grails-2.4.4/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar -Xverify:none -Dspringloaded.synchronize=true -Djdk.reflect.allowGetCallerClass=true -Dspringloaded=\""profile=grails;cacheDir=C:\Users\jpeil/.grails/2.4.4/"\" ) ) 

C:\Users\jpeil>set STARTER_MAIN_CLASS=org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter 

C:\Users\jpeil>set STARTER_CONF=C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4\conf\groovy-starter.conf 

C:\Users\jpeil>set JAVA_EXE=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe 

C:\Users\jpeil>set TOOLS_JAR=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\lib\tools.jar 

C:\Users\jpeil>set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx768M -Xms64M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -javaagent:C:/grails-2.4.4/grails-2.4.4/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar -Xverify:none -Dspringloaded.synchronize=true -Djdk.reflect.allowGetCallerClass=true -Dspringloaded=\""profile=grails;cacheDir=C:\Users\jpeil/.grails/2.4.4/"\" 

C:\Users\jpeil>set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx768M -Xms64M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -javaagent:C:/grails-2.4.4/grails-2.4.4/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar -Xverify:none -Dspringloaded.synchronize=true -Djdk.reflect.allowGetCallerClass=true -Dspringloaded=\""profile=grails;cacheDir=C:\Users\jpeil/.grails/2.4.4/"\" -Dprogram.name="" 

C:\Users\jpeil>set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx768M -Xms64M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -javaagent:C:/grails-2.4.4/grails-2.4.4/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar -Xverify:none -Dspringloaded.synchronize=true -Djdk.reflect.allowGetCallerClass=true -Dspringloaded=\""profile=grails;cacheDir=C:\Users\jpeil/.grails/2.4.4/"\" -Dprogram.name="" -Dgrails.home="C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4" 

C:\Users\jpeil>set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx768M -Xms64M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -javaagent:C:/grails-2.4.4/grails-2.4.4/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar -Xverify:none -Dspringloaded.synchronize=true -Djdk.reflect.allowGetCallerClass=true -Dspringloaded=\""profile=grails;cacheDir=C:\Users\jpeil/.grails/2.4.4/"\" -Dprogram.name="" -Dgrails.home="C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4" -Dgrails.version=2.4.4 

C:\Users\jpeil>set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx768M -Xms64M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -javaagent:C:/grails-2.4.4/grails-2.4.4/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar -Xverify:none -Dspringloaded.synchronize=true -Djdk.reflect.allowGetCallerClass=true -Dspringloaded=\""profile=grails;cacheDir=C:\Users\jpeil/.grails/2.4.4/"\" -Dprogram.name="" -Dgrails.home="C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4" -Dgrails.version=2.4.4 -Dbase.dir=. 

C:\Users\jpeil>set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx768M -Xms64M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -javaagent:C:/grails-2.4.4/grails-2.4.4/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar -Xverify:none -Dspringloaded.synchronize=true -Djdk.reflect.allowGetCallerClass=true -Dspringloaded=\""profile=grails;cacheDir=C:\Users\jpeil/.grails/2.4.4/"\" -Dprogram.name="" -Dgrails.home="C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4" -Dgrails.version=2.4.4 -Dbase.dir=. -Dtools.jar="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\lib\tools.jar" 

C:\Users\jpeil>set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx768M -Xms64M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -javaagent:C:/grails-2.4.4/grails-2.4.4/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar -Xverify:none -Dspringloaded.synchronize=true -Djdk.reflect.allowGetCallerClass=true -Dspringloaded=\""profile=grails;cacheDir=C:\Users\jpeil/.grails/2.4.4/"\" -Dprogram.name="" -Dgrails.home="C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4" -Dgrails.version=2.4.4 -Dbase.dir=. -Dtools.jar="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\lib\tools.jar" -Dgroovy.starter.conf="C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4\conf\groovy-starter.conf" 

C:\Users\jpeil>if exist "C:\Users\jpeil/.groovy/postinit.bat" call "C:\Users\jpeil/.groovy/postinit.bat" 

C:\Users\jpeil>CALL "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe" -server -Xmx768M -Xms64M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -javaagent:C:/grails-2.4.4/grails-2.4.4/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar -Xverify:none -Dspringloaded.synchronize=true -Djdk.reflect.allowGetCallerClass=true -Dspringloaded=\""profile=grails;cacheDir=C:\Users\jpeil/.grails/2.4.4/"\" -Dprogram.name="" -Dgrails.home="C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4" -Dgrails.version=2.4.4 -Dbase.dir=. -Dtools.jar="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\lib\tools.jar" -Dgroovy.starter.conf="C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4\conf\groovy-starter.conf" -classpath "C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-2.3.7.jar;C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4\dist\grails-bootstrap-2.4.4.jar" org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --conf "C:\grails-2.4.4\grails-2.4.4\conf\groovy-starter.conf" --classpath "" "" 
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844

Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"

C:\Users\jpeil>if "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" endlocal

C:\Users\jpeil>if "" == "on" pause
```

"grails --stacktrace --verbose" gives me the same as "grails", nothing more than the java exceptions

Comment: Must be environmental then, probably permissions. Please edit the question and add the stacktrace (omit any huge redundant sections).

Comment: Thanks Burt. Please let me know how to get a stacktrace.

Comment: It should be there in the output. You can see more with a couple of flags: `grails --verbose --stacktrace <command>` (looks like you can omit the command). Since it's a stack overflow you'll likely have the same pattern of ~5-20 lines repeated, so you should remove most of those before adding here, but leave a few so we know what's happening :) Or just add all the output, we can scroll.